# MS-Access: Select start date and date for each fiscal month

Tags: sql, ms-access

SQL newbie here. So I have a table that reads

```
start_date  |  end_date   |   fiscal_month  | fiscal_year
------------| ------------|-----------------|-------------
1/1/2017    |  1/1/2017   |        1        |   2017
1/2/2017    |  1/8/2017   |        1        |   2017
1/9/2017    |  1/15/2017  |        1        |   2017
1/16/2017   |  1/22/2017  |        1        |   2017
1/23/2017   |  1/29/2017  |        1        |   2017
1/30/2017   |  2/5/2017   |        2        |   2017
2/6/2017    |  2/12/2017  |        2        |   2017
2/13/2017   |  2/19/2017  |        2        |   2017
2/20/2017   |  2/26/2017  |        2        |   2017
2/27/2017   |  3/5/2017   |        3        |   2017
```

...And so on for the year of 2017

I want to extract just the start and end dates for each ***fiscal*** month

I'm trying to write a query that'll output

```
start_date  |  end_date   
------------| ---------   
1/1/2017    |  1/29/2017  
1/30/2017   |  2/26/2017  
2/27/2017   |  3/26/2017
```

...And so on for the year.

I could grab the start and end dates for each month individually fairly easily with

```
SELECT First(start_date), Last(end_date)
FROM fiscal_calendar
WHERE year=2017 AND fiscal_month=1
```

But I don't know how to get all of the months in a single query. I'm sure it's a simple solution for a SQL veteran, but I'm racking my brain. From my understanding, MS Access doesn't really have loops in their SQL language, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use min and max

```
  SELECT min(start_date), max(end_date)
  FROM fiscal_calendar
  WHERE year=2017 AND fiscal_month=1
```

and for all the months

```
  SELECT fiscal_month, min(start_date), max(end_date)
  FROM fiscal_calendar
  WHERE year=2017 
  group by fiscal_month
```

and for a version with desired formatting!

```
SELECT  min(start_date) as start_date, max(end_date) as end_date
  FROM fiscal_calendar 
  WHERE year=2017 
  GROUP BY fiscal_month
```

Comment: Awesome. I knew it was a simple solution, I'm just very unfamiliar with SQL. Thank you.